# Create 3D globe of Earth with one polygon for each country

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, maya

I am creating a 3D sphere of the Earth for Unity and I need to have one polygon for each country. Each country has a set of 2D points which are proyected into 3D points based on proyection. But when I create the polygon some vertices are joining incorrectly.
I used Maya to create the polygons with this code

```
with open("C:\\Users\\patilanz\\Downloads\\geo_countries_medium.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)




def to_3d(x,y):
    #convert from degrees to radians
    longitude = math.radians(x)
    latitude = math.radians(y)

    # select a radius:
    radius = 10

    # project to 3d
    return (
        radius * math.cos(latitude) * math.cos(longitude), 
        radius * math.cos(latitude) * math.sin(longitude), 
        radius * math.sin(latitude)
    )

for feat in d.get("features"):
    r = []
    coords = feat.get("geometry").get("coordinates")
    type = feat.get("geometry").get("type")
    for coord in coords:
        for c in coord:
            if type == "MultiPolygon":
                r = []
                for a in c:
                    r.append(to_3d(a[0],a[1]))
                poly = cmds.polyCreateFacet(p=r)
                poly = cmds.rename(feat.get("properties").get("name"))
            else:
                r.append(to_3d(c[0],c[1]))

    if not type == "MultiPoligon":
        poly = cmds.polyCreateFacet(p=r)
        poly = cmds.rename(feat.get("properties").get("name"))

cmds.polySphere(r = 10 * 0.98)
```

[The problem of incorrect joining vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXf7Q.png)

I found that this guy was trying to do the same think https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/drawing-countries-on-top-of-a-3d-sphere-from-set-of-boundaries.html

But I don't know how to implement that in Maya or in Unity.

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: I added it because I think I found the solution in Java Processing, but I need help to use it in Maya or Unity.